# Implementing a button on the header bar, react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a button on the right of the header bar so that it will change the order of the list, and i was thinking to have a state of the order and flip it as the button will be pressed and check wether that is true and false and show the list in the requested order.

But i get an error saying `Notes.flipState is not a function. (In 'Notes.flipState()', 'Notes.flipState is undefined)`

Any idea why is this hapening and how to solve it, below is my function flipState() and the navigationOptions.

```
    state = {
        desc: true
    }
    flipState() {
        this.setState({ desc: !this.state.desc})
    }
    static navigationOptions = ({ flipState }) => {
        return {
            title: 'Upcoming Movies',
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerRight: () => (
                <BorderlessButton
                    onPress={() => this.flipState()}
                    style={{ marginRight: 20 }}>
                    <Icon
                        name={'sort-alpha-asc'}
                        size={25}
                        color='gray'
                    />
                </BorderlessButton>
            ),
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a `"public"` method inside of static method. "Play" with navigation state to pass data between header and content.

See `setParams` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Comment: I don´t see how i can use this, but I am going to try my best.

Comment: see @SachihiroTakamori answer

Answer (score 0):

A static method won't be able to access this .you have to pass function through the navigation params.

like

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      flipStat: this.flipStat,
    });
  }
```

get from navigationOption

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
 const flipStat = navigation.state.params.flipStat;
return </>
}
```